Ошибка System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'C:\Users\Asl\source\repos\TwelveMonths\TwelveMonths\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\1.jpg'
Почему появляется ошибка System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'C:\Users\Asl\source\repos\TwelveMonths\TwelveMonths\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\1.jpg' откуда компилятор вообще находит 1.jpg, у меня она где-то упоминается ?
namespace TwelveMonths
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            showMonthPicture();
        }

        private void monthCalendar_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            showMonthPicture();
        }
        private void showMonthPicture()
        { 
            string month = monthCalendar.SelectionStart.Month.ToString();
            pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile($"");
        }
    }
}


Я не понимаю почему ищется файл 1.jpg я же ведь даже не прописывал.
КОД ДИЗАЙНЕРА:
namespace TwelveMonths
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            monthCalendar = new MonthCalendar();
            pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)pictureBox).BeginInit();
            SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // monthCalendar
            // 
            monthCalendar.Location = new Point(5, 9);
            monthCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1;
            monthCalendar.Name = "monthCalendar";
            monthCalendar.TabIndex = 0;
            monthCalendar.DateChanged += monthCalendar_DateChanged;
            // 
            // pictureBox
            // 
            pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox.Name = "pictureBox";
            pictureBox.Size = new Size(800, 450);
            pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox.TabIndex = 1;
            pictureBox.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(8F, 20F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new Size(800, 450);
            Controls.Add(monthCalendar);
            Controls.Add(pictureBox);
            Icon = (Icon)resources.GetObject("$this.Icon");
            Name = "Form1";
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            Text = "12 месяцов";
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)pictureBox).EndInit();
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        #endregion

        private MonthCalendar monthCalendar;
        private PictureBox pictureBox;
    }
}


Image.FromFile($""); вам о чём-либо говорит?

В какой строке ошибка появляется? Покажите полный стектрейс. / Что в InitializeComponent();? Возможно вы в дизайнере задали 1.jpg

@Chaos_Sower то что оно пустое меня это и странно, даже при пустом пути компилятор ищет какой-то 1.jpg.

@AlexanderPetrov что такое стектрейс?

Да, ошибка специфичнее, я поспешил. 1) Image.FromFile($""); — это строка вызовит исключение (вы же путь не указали, где он ещё будет искать изображение по-вашему?) 2) Вы добавляли это изображение в ресурсы? Хоть как-то использовали его до возникшей ошибки?

Возможно вы задали в дизацнере. Поставьте курсор на InitializeComponent() и нажмите F12, и там поищите, где 1.jpg

Когда хоть исключение возникает-то? Закомментируйте вызов метода showMonthPicture();. Ошибка возникает после этого? — значит, 100 % дело в InitializeComponent();

@aepot я добавил код дизайнера и там ничего не нашел про 1.jpg

@Chaos_Sower @aepot я добавил код дизайнера и там ничего не нашел про 1.jpg, и после того как закоментил showMonthPicture() так же происходит ошиба.

Закройте проект, удалите папки bin и obj, откройте снова и пересоберите.

@aepot Спасибо помогли!
